# Не добавляются заказы в phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Есть вот такой код:

```
$host = 'localhost';  // Хост, у нас все локально
$user = '**********';    // Имя созданного вами пользователя
$pass = '********'; // Установленный вами пароль пользователю
$db_name = '*********';   // Имя базы данных
$result = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name); // Соединяемся с базой
```

и

```
 $order  = rand(100009, 999999);
 $sql_date = date("m.d.y");
 $sql_order = $order;
 $sql_nickname = $_POST['nickname'];
 $sql_robux = $_POST['robux'];
 $sql_promocode = $_POST['promocode'];
 $add_buyer = "INSERT INTO buyers (date, ord, nickname, robux, promo) 
               VALUES ('$sql_date','$sql_order','$sql_nickname', '$sql_robux', '$sql_promocode')";


 if(!$add_buyer) 
 {
     echo "Заказ не добавлен";
 } else {
     echo "Заказ как бы добавлен, но ты чекни базу";
 }
```

Он на странице оплаты заказа, без всяких функций и т.д. Т.е при заходе на эту страницу по сути код должен выполнятся, но этого не происходит, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: У вас в примере синтаксическая ошибка. В реальном коде она тоже есть?

Comment: в $add_buyer? или?

Comment: В `$add_buyer` не закрыты двойные кавачки

Comment: Отредактировал, в реальном коде такого нет.

Comment: То, что вы в __переменную__ записали текст запроса не значит, что запрос выполнился.

Comment:  не понимаю, хд. Объясните)

Comment: Что непонятного? Что делает `$add_buyer = "INSERT ...';` по-вашему? По-моему - это присваивание строки в переменную `$add_buyer`. Никакого взаимодействия с базой данных в предоставленном коде я не вижу.

Comment: У меня была форма и этот же самый код, ну и в форму вписывались данные, так они обрабатывались и в базу сохранялись

Comment: Значит код был __не тот же самый__.

Comment: CTRL+C CTRL+V и все

Comment: Еще раз, последний: `$add_buyer = "INSERT INTO buyers ...'` это __не__ выполнение запроса к бд, это запись значения в переменную. Запрос к БД выполняется функциями типа `mysqli_query`. Вот и разбирайтесь, где вы их потеряли или просто вы их забыли вставить в вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы должны выполнить следующий запрос:

```
$request = $result->query($add_buyer);

if (!$request) {
    echo "Заказ не добавлен";
} else {
    echo "Заказ как бы добавлен, но ты чекни базу";
}
```

Comment: Я сделал заного проверку добавлено ли в  базу или нет. И как то все это заработало)
if(!mysqli_query($result, $add_result))
        {
            echo "Запись не добавлена";
        } else {
            echo "Запись добавлена";
        }

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена - добавил проверку, и всё заработало.

```
if(!mysqli_query($result, $add_result)) { 
    echo "Запись не добавлена"; 
} else { 
    echo "Запись добавлена"; 
}
```

Comment: А что такое `$add_result`? В вопросе эта переменная не фигурирует